# how to debug configure.sh errors when compiling rsync on Yosemite

Tags: xcode, homebrew, gcc, rsync

I am trying to build myself a new version of rsync 3.1.1 under Mac OS 10.10.3, as the mac comes with an older version, and the [project](https://rsync.samba.org/) does not distribute binaries.

I followed [this](http://selfsuperinit.com/2014/01/04/an-updated-rsync-3-1-0-for-mavericks/) simple script but it hiccups on gcc. (I am not sure why — though I removed XCode to save disk space, I have the command line tools, incl. gcc in /usr/bin etc.) I would try to build it with clang instead, but how exactly shall I do that?

Here is the error from the script:

```
configure.sh: Configuring rsync 3.1.1
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
checking whether to include debugging
symbols... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure.sh: error: in `/Users/laszlosandor/Downloads/rsync-3.1.1':
configure.sh: error: C
compiler cannot create executable
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Or even more from the relevant sections of `config.log`:

```
gcc: warning: couldn't understand kern.osversion '14.3.0
configure.sh:2893: $? = 0
configure.sh:2882: gcc -v >&5
gcc: warning: couldn't understand kern.osversion '14.3.0
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0/4.8.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8-20120930/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.0 20120930 (experimental) (GCC) 
configure.sh:2893: $? = 0
configure.sh:2882: gcc -V >&5
gcc: warning: couldn't understand kern.osversion '14.3.0
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure.sh:2893: $? = 1
configure.sh:2882: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: warning: couldn't understand kern.osversion '14.3.0
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure.sh:2893: $? = 1
configure.sh:2913: checking whether the C compiler works
configure.sh:2935: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
gcc: warning: couldn't understand kern.osversion '14.3.0
ld: library not found for -lgcc_ext.10.4
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure.sh:2939: $? = 1
configure.sh:2977: result: no
configure.sh: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define RSYNC_VERSION "3.1.1"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure.sh:2982: error: in `/Users/laszlosandor/Downloads/rsync-3.1.1':
configure.sh:2984: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

By the way, I know I could have just stuck with Homebrew, but now I want to learn.

Comment: @bmike Also, I like that you're interested in the specifics of the problem, but I was interested in a specific solution. Why can't ask for that too? I don't see why `clang` would be irrelevant here.

Comment: Feel free to revery my title change if it's not a help or what you look for. The detail in config.log is awesome. Last question - does `gcc --version` show **Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)**

Comment: If you want more information on the problem please tell us what you've tried so far. Particularly how you removed Xcode but kept the command-line tools. It appears from the errors that you have GCC installed through brew perhaps?

Comment: I simply deleted Xcode, I think. Yes, maybe gcc came with homebrew. So that's a problem? And it makes no sense to try clang instead?

Comment: The `gcc` that comes with Xcode is actually `clang`. :) I'd try `brew uninstall gcc`, then `xcode-select --install`, then try `./configure` again. Your system just appears to be a bit confused right now.

Comment: upon `brew uninstall gcc`: `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc`

Comment: If you have homebrew anyway use it for rsync

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the install of the command-line developer tools on your Mac.

Try installing again with the following command. This should install the command-line tools alone.

```
 xcode-select --install
```

The script is testing the command-line tools to see whether a compatible version is installed but is getting back confusing responses. This is why it fails.

Comment: I get `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

Comment: Type `/usr/bin/gcc -v` into a Terminal window and let us know what it says.

Comment: `Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1`
`Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)`
`Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0`
`Thread model: posix`

Comment: Cool. Now try just `gcc -v`.

Comment: Weird.
`gcc: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘14.3.0`
`Using built-in specs.`
`COLLECT_GCC=gcc`
`COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0/4.8.0/lto-wrapper`
`Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0`
`Configured with: ../gcc-4.8-20120930/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran`
`Thread model: posix`
`gcc version 4.8.0 20120930 (experimental) (GCC)`

Comment: Now try `brew uninstall gcc` and then `gcc -v`. :)

Comment: I told you in another comment, I get `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22808/discussion-between-alistair-mcmillan-and-laszlo).

Comment: With the correct gcc, the script fails much later, but with `./install-sh -c -d /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -c  -m 755 rsync /usr/local/bin
install: /usr/local/bin/rsync: No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 71
logout`