# Command line tool installed, but gcc/g++ compiler not working

Tags: xcode, command-line, gcc

Heads up, I have a similar problem such as in this question, but it wasn't resolved:

[how to debug configure.sh errors when compiling rsync on Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180750/how-to-debug-configure-sh-errors-when-compiling-rsync-on-yosemite/180767#180767)

So basically I am looking to compile code via the command line, which works fine with clang++, but when i use gcc/g++ I get this warning:

`g++: Warnung: kern.osversion nicht erkannt: »14.3.0`

This line in english would be:

gcc: warning: couldn't understand kern.osversion '14.3.0

When I type g++ -v, this is my answer:

```
g++: Warnung: kern.osversion nicht erkannt: »14.3.0
Es werden eingebaute Spezifikationen verwendet.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0/4.9.0/lto-wrapper
Ziel: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Konfiguriert mit: ../gcc-4.9.0/configure --enable-languages=fortran
Thread-Modell: posix
gcc-Version 4.9.0 (GCC)
```

As mentioned before, typing clang++ -v gives:

Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0 Thread model: posix

So all good.

Now since clang++ and Xcode compile fine, why bother you would say, but I just tried to install gnuplot and that doesn't work at all and the gcc problem keeps appearing.

I would be so grateful if someone new what was wrong. At the least it would be good to know how to install gnuplot without gcc functioning. I tried the install with the usual commands: ./configure make make install

Thx a lot!

P.S. I run Yosemite and am pretty sure (installed it like 3 times) that I have installed the latest command line tools.
As I gather from the discussion in the other thread is that something might have been installed by hand which should not have been. Unfortunately I am not that good with unix etc. that I'd be able to figure out what went wrong.

Edit1:
Many threads that I find with a similar issue have as solution that the command line tool are installed. Just to be sure I typed again:

xcode-select --install , which gives me:

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use     "Software Update" to install updates
```

Edit2: This link https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/36944 seems to have a similar problem, and it is also ressolved, but I cannot make their solution work as I don't know what brew is, nor do I have gcc-4.9 working. But I thought this might give a hint.

Edit3: As is suggested in one of the comments, I tink the problem lies in too many different version of gcc (and other stuff) being installed in various places. I have managed to now link to the recent version of gcc I installed with homebrew so that g++ works as a compiler, but gcc still does not work. I also still get the kern.osversion warning. So the problem is not really solved. I would still be interested in someone maybe showing me how to get rid of every compiler, command line tool, and what not and start from scratch...

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of Xcode and the command line tools?

Comment: Yes, I checked numerous times that they are installed, so I am pretty confident with that!

Comment: What is the output of `type clang++; type gcc`?

Comment: Also, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180750/how-to-debug-configure-sh-errors-when-compiling-rsync-on-yosemite shows a similar problem

Comment: output of type clang++ is: clang++ is hashed (/usr/bin/clang++) and the output of type gcc is: gcc is hashed (/usr/local/bin/gcc)

Comment: that is the same link I post at the top I believe, unfortunately the problem wasn't ressolved, at least not in public

Comment: Your `gcc` seems to installed in a non-standard location, so updating Xcode probably won't help here. Where did you get it from, homebrew?

Comment: No, that's the thing. I am pretty sure I never installed it, at least not knowingly. The one thing that was installed was gfortran. I would not bet my life on this though... All more than a year ago. I installed homebrew just now and typed brew reinstall get and it's working hard just now

Comment: Can you run `ls -l /usr/local/bin/gcc`? And `ls -l /usr/bin/gcc` as well?

Comment: For the first I get: -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1159812 24 Mai  2014 /usr/local/bin/gcc     and for the second I get: -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  14160 29 Sep  2014 /usr/bin/gcc , which seems to confirm what I write in Edit3. I wish I just could start from scratch completely lol...

Comment: Renaming the one in local to something else might get you going...

Comment: And if it is of interest, the latest says: papc-cmdtc-07:BookTutorial maximilianschulz$ ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/bin/gcc-4.9 
-r-xr-xr-x  3 maximilianschulz  admin  1126272 13 Apr 04:17 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.9.2_1/bin/gcc-4.9

Comment: `brew uninstall gcc` might help then (but fortran may break due to that)

Comment: I'll try that tonight, thanks. Will report on it later. Need to go now

Comment: Note that Xcode does not now install gcc 0 the one in /usr/bin is a stub - use a package manager to install gunplay e.g. Home-brew which you **HAVE(( installed or Macports - but not more than one

Comment: This link was posted in the GNU Fortran Project mailing list: http://coudert.name/software/gfortran-5.2-Yosemite.dmg